# Shopping script which support many optional items on checkout

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I want to know have shopping script support checkout module like **[this](http://www.xoticpc.com/asus-n61jqb2-p-2876.html?wconfigure=yes)**?

If build it from scratch, what is the key to make something like that. Let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what you want it looks like [a bundle product](http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/video-bundle-kitting-in-magento-11/) would be the best match.